# Downloading Only Newest File Using Wget / Curl

Tags: bash, shell, curl, wget

How would I use wget or curl to download the newest file in a directory?

This seems really easy, however the filename won't always be predictable, and as new data comes in it'll be replaced with a random filename.

Specifically, the directory I wish to download data from has the following naming structure, where the last string of characters is a randomly generated timestamp:

```
MRMS_RotationTrackML1440min_00.50_20160530-175837.grib2.gz
MRMS_RotationTrackML1440min_00.50_20160530-182639.grib2.gz
MRMS_RotationTrackML1440min_00.50_20160530-185637.grib2.gz
```

The randomly generated timestamp is in the format of: {hour}{minute}{second}

The directory in question is here: http://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/2D/RotationTrackML1440min/

Could it have to be something with something in the headers, where you'd use curl to sift through the last-modified timestamp?

Any help would be appreciated here, thanks in advance.

Comment: huh, a "randomly generated timestamp"? Why would one do that?

Comment: @StefanHegny - The data doesn't come in in exact increments, so it's by definition random in a sense if I were to create a script which would fetch it, say every two minutes.

Comment: not meant personally, just sounded a little bit funny - nevermind

Comment: @StefanHegny - Yeah haha, I tried to find a way to describe the sporadic creation of the files.

Comment: sometimes it takes a bit longer till I get it... I think now I got it, but could not do better than amaksr anyway.. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run following command periodically:

```
wget -r -nc --level=1 http://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/2D/RotationTrackML1440min/
```

It will download recursively whatever is new in the directory after last run.